# How to toggle jQuery Responsive-Tabs on hover, instead of click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made an accordion menu using jQuery Responsive-Tabs. The panels open/close on mouse click. How can I Modify this to open/close panels on mouse hover?

This is how I am initializing responsive tabs:

```
/*==========  Tabs Responsive ==========*/
function TabsResponsive(){
    if($('#tabs-responsive').length){
        $('#tabs-responsive').responsiveTabs({
            rotate: false,
            active:0,
            startCollapsed: 'accordion',
            collapsible: 'accordion',
            animation: 'slide',
            duration:300,
            setHash: false
        });
    }
}
```

This my simplified HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs-responsive">
    <ul class="nav-tab" id="classifiedMenu">
        <li><a href="#books" aria-controls="books" data-toggle="tab">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sports" aria-controls="sports" data-toggle="tab">Sports</a></li>
    </ul>                                    
    <div id="classifiedContent" class="tab-content overflow-auto">
        <div class="tab-pane classified" id="books">
            <div class="text-content">
                <ul class="classified-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Comics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cookbooks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>       

         <div class="tab-pane classified" id="sports">
            <div class="text-content">
                <ul class="classified-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Cycling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the relevant `javascript`/`jQuery`? Can't tell you how to modify something without seeing how you bind the event to the function...

Comment: I can see in chrome dev tool, when I click on a button, r-tabs-state-active is added to the corresponding content... I thought Jquery.ResponsiveTabs.js does this? I am using a template for this site, so I have one additional JS which came with the template.

Comment: Then it would be relevant for you to clearly state the use of `Jquery.ResponsiveTabs.js` since you haven't mentioned anything about it in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out the Readme of that plugin :

https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs/blob/master/README.md

Adding the following to the settings block where you add collapsible, start collapsed etc.., should work

```
event: 'mouseover'
```